# Integration bounds with $P(XY < z)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In the following problem, why are the bounds of integration what they are? I think $x$ should be integrated between $0$ and $\infty$. If $X$ is greater than $z$ it's OK as long as $y < \frac z x$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are correct.  This solution appears to be mistaken.

Comment: You are indeed correct, exactly for the reason you indicate. What is the source?

Comment: please rephrase the question : why what? is not understood.

Comment: I knew it! Thanks guys. The source is http://personal.vu.nl/h.c.tijms/ExamQuestionsUP.pdf

Comment: @Adelafif ?? What is not understood?

Comment: @badmax Probably a simple copy-paste error from 11E-13 which has a very similar solution.